# MySQL query from multiple tables?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables say named `table_1` and `table_2`. The schema is somewhat as follows.

**table_1**

```
+----+--------+-----+------------+
| id | reg_no | ... | table_2_id |
+----+--------+-----+------------+
```

**table_2**

```
+----+-----+
| id | ... |
+----+-----+
```

The column `table_2_id` in `table_1` refers to the column `id` in `table_2`. Now, I have to get the `table_2_id` for a specific `reg_no` and then use that `table_2_id` to get data from `table_2`.

I currently do it as follows and it works.

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT table_2_id from table_1 WHERE reg_no = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $reg_no);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($table_2_id);
$stmt->fetch();
$stmt->close();
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * from table_1 WHERE id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("i", $table_2_id);
$stmt->execute();
...
```

Is this the correct way to do it? Is there some other more efficient query to perform this task?

Comment: You could try joining the two tables together, and then executing a single query to get your result.

Comment: try something like this `SELECT table_2.* FROM table_1 LEFT JOIN table_2 ON table_1.table_2_id=table_2.id WHERE table_1.reg_no = ?`

Comment: @gdros Please post it as an answer with a bit of explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be more efficient to do this with one query like this:

```
SELECT table_2.* 
FROM table_1 LEFT JOIN table_2 ON table_1.table_2_id=table_2.id 
WHERE table_1.reg_no = ?
```

`table_1 LEFT JOIN table_2 ON table_1.table_2_id=table_2.id` will join table_1 and table_2. 
More specifically it will create a table which will have all columns from both table_1 and table_2 
and then it will put in it all rows from table_1. Also when there is a row in table_2 with id same as the
table_2_id it will also fill the tables_2's columns.

The above action will be limited to only those rows where `table_1.reg_no = ?`

Finally with `SELECT table_2.*` we get only the columns from the table_2 as in your example.

Comment: Just a query: Wouldn't `INNER JOIN` be better for my use case?

Comment: Well in the exact case yes but generally it depends on what you want to do. The INNER JOIN will return to you no rows when there is no relevant row in table_2 and LEFT JOIN will return rows with null columns for every row in table_1 that have the specified reg_no

Answer (score 1):

The query using join

```
SELECT t2.* 
FROM table_1 t1
JOIN table_2 t2 ON t1.table_2_id = t2.id
WHERE t2.t1reg_no = ?
```

Comment: Can you explain it a bit?

Comment: You can read about joins at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html . What exactly explanation is needed?

Comment: He wants the data from table_2 not from table_1... @Serg

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT T2.* FROM table_2 T2 
LEFT JOIN table_1 T1 ON T1.table_2_id = T2.id 
WHERE T1.reg_no = ?;
```

## Example

**table_1**

```
id   reg_no   table_2_id
1     001        1
2     002        2
3     003        4 
4     004        7
5     005        8
```

**table_2**

```
id  column_test
1      A
2      B
3      C
4      D
5      E
6      F
7      G
```

**Query**

```
SELECT T2.* FROM table_2 T2 
LEFT JOIN table_1 T1 ON T1.table_2_id = T2.id 
WHERE T1.reg_no = 003;
```

**Output**

```
id  column_test
4     D
```